# Is there a way to clip areas that are intersecting in Cartodb?

Tags: carto, clip

I am new to cartodb and wish to know how can one clip only the areas that are intersecting?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ST_Intersects()](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) function then save your query as a new table by going to Options > Table From Query.

SQL code would be something like this:

`SELECT a.* FROM polygon_table AS a, point_table AS b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.the_geom)`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use ST_Difference() to get the region in geometry A that does not intersect with geometry B.

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html

```
SELECT
 ST_Difference(a.the_geom, b.the_geom) AS the_geom
FROM
 table1 a, table2 b
```